# ARM Assembly Optimisation - Basic

Tags: assembly, arm, computer-science, micro-optimization

```
LDR R1, a
LDR R2, b
MOV R0, #0
loop ADD R0, R0, R1
SUB R2, R2, #1
CMP R2, #0
BNE loop
STR R0, c
```

1. State two cases where the program could produce an erroneous result, and show
   how each case could be detected by modifications to the program.
2. Give two different ways that the program could be modified to execute
   more quickly.

---

My answers-

1. when b<0, when either one of a or b is a string (how do we check this?), when a is way too large (so the result might overflow) (how do we check this?)
2. Using MUL operation instead of the whole loop (as the program is essentially doing c=a*b), second?

Comment: Strictly speaking one cannot tell which result is considered "erroneous" unless this is somehow specified in the task description. This sequence of instructions will perform the programmed actions on the contents of the registers and that's it. It is up to a human to interpret whether the result makes any sense or not and this depends on the context of the task. 2. Another way to speed it up a bit is to use SUBS instead of SUB and get rid of CMP - the Z flag will be set by SUBS.

Comment: a, b and c are addresses in memory. LDR reads one word (32-bit), STR stores one word. So, there is no such thing as "string" here, the "program" operates on 32-bit binary numbers. Is there anything that was given as part of this exercise that you did not provide in the question? Like, has it been mentioned anywhere in the description that this code implements c=a*b? Any high level (pseudo-)code specifying variable types/sizes?

Comment: No, there was no extra information other than this but I have got to the final answers now. They are -

1. Error cases- when b<0, this will enter into an infinite loop and when a is too large, the result will overflow (as you said it is upto human interpretation) 
2. Using MUL and using SUBS

Comment: Your answers will probably suit "them" (whoever "they" are). But *when b<0, this will enter into an infinite loop* - is wrong, it won't be infinite. Just pretty long but R2 will still get down to 0 and the loop will stop. To me even *b < 0* looks weird here as this is again the matter of interpretation. You choose to interpret *b* as a signed integer, which is not mentioned anywhere in the task description. It might as well be unsigned, representing the range from 0 to (2^32 - 1).

Comment: This code is obviously treating `b` as an unsigned integer.  We conclude that based on the fact that it assumes the value is non-negative by counting it down toward zero.  Nothing in the code implies that it should be signed so there's no reason to assume that.  This is why asm should be commented!

Comment: However, the `b == 0` case does look like a real problem.  This does appear to be doing an unsigned multiply, but without a `cjz` or `tst`/`beq` to skip the loop, it will uselessly run 2^32 iterations instead of 0.  Multiplying by `0x1 0000 0000` shifts `a` so far left that the result will always be zero, so the answer is actually still correct.  (@tum_).  So actually it's just another performance problem, not correctness, for the c<1 unsigned case.